# Compare two cells in a html table and highlight row if different

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an HTML table (tree table precisely but it doesn't matter) and it has several columns. For each row, it is very important that the values in one of the columns should be higher than the other column. If that is not the case then I'd like to highlight that entire row. How do I do that?

My HTML code looks like this:

```
<table id="stepstats-list-exp"> 
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th> name   </th>
          <th> elp_01  </th>
          <th> elp_20  </th>
          <th> scal </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr data-tt-id=864845 data-tt-parent-id=>
          <td> &#39;Init&#39; </td>
          <td class="elp_01">  0 </td>
          <td class="elp_20"> 0 </td>
          <td class="scal"> 0.00 </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr data-tt-id=864846 data-tt-parent-id=864845>
          <td> &#39;Update&#39; </td>
          <td class="elp_01">  0 </td>
          <td class="elp_20"> 0 </td>
          <td class="scal"> 0.00 </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr data-tt-id=864847 data-tt-parent-id=>
          <td> &#39;Load&#39; </td>
          <td class="elp_01">  32 </td>
          <td class="elp_20"> 31 </td>
          <td class="scal"> 1.03 </td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

In all my test cases, `elp_20` should always be smaller than `elp_01`. If not, the entire row needs to be highlighted. For that purpose, I have this jQuery code that doesn't seem to be working. For each `tr` row, I'm checking each `td` column and comparing values.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* Highlight row if elp_20 > elp_01 */
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#stepstats-list-exp tr").each(function () {
        $(this).find('td').each(function(){
          if (parseInt($(".elp_20").text(), 10) < parseInt($(".elp_01").text(), 10)) { 
            $(this).parent("tr").css('background-color', 'crimson');
            $(this).parent("tr").css('font-weight','bold');
            $(this).parent("tr").css('color','white');
          }
        });
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This working snippet accesses the table rows as an `html collection` that can be looped through to compare the values represented by the contents of the second and third cell of each row. An inline style attribute it used to highlight the row (alternative styling could be made by adding or toggling class names if something more complex is needed)

```js
let tableRows = document.getElementById("stepstats-list-exp").getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (let i=0; i<tableRows.length; i++)

  if (Number(tableRows[i].children[2].innerText) >= Number(tableRows[i].children[1].innerText)) {
  tableRows[i].setAttribute("style", "background: yellow");

}
```

```html
<table id="stepstats-list-exp"> 
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th> name   </th>
          <th> elp_01  </th>
          <th> elp_20  </th>
          <th> scal </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr data-tt-id=864845 data-tt-parent-id=>
          <td> &#39;Init&#39; </td>
          <td class="elp_01">  0 </td>
          <td class="elp_20"> 0 </td>
          <td class="scal"> 0.00 </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr data-tt-id=864846 data-tt-parent-id=864845>
          <td> &#39;Update&#39; </td>
          <td class="elp_01">  0 </td>
          <td class="elp_20"> 0 </td>
          <td class="scal"> 0.00 </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr data-tt-id=864847 data-tt-parent-id=>
          <td> &#39;Load&#39; </td>
          <td class="elp_01">  32 </td>
          <td class="elp_20"> 31 </td>
          <td class="scal"> 1.03 </td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: There is one problem with this code as it is interfering with my other code. I have a tree table which means there is a hierarchy view in the name column. The table starts with a collapsed tree view. When the above code is executed, all the highlighted rows were added at the bottom of a closed tree. I need to click "expand all" and then "collapse all" to restore the correct view. The implementation of expand/collapse buttons is another javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate through the classes, add them to a variable and iterate with a for loop, if you need to iterate one `elp_01` to all `elp_20` just map it.

Here's an example:

```
let firstColumn = document.getElementsByClassName('elp_01').innerText
let secondColumn = document.getElementsByClassName('elp_20').innerText

for (let i = 0; i < firstColumn.length; i ++) {
    if (firstColumn[i] > secondColumn[i]) {
        // Something - maybe add a class in css to color the row and add it to the element
    }
    else {
        // Something else
    }
}
```